# Transforming wrenches between points and between frames

Tags: screw-theory

[image]

I am having a hard time understanding the transformation of wrenches between points and represented in different frames. For e.g. Consider a unit wrench passing through $r_{end}$. When expressed in frame $x_2,y_2$

$\begin{equation}
^2\\\$_{rend} = \begin{bmatrix} (0,2,0)\times(1,0,0)\\(1,0,0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-2\\1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$

I wanted to find shift the wrench from $r_{end}$ to $r_{i}$, so that the equivalent wrench will have the same effect on the frame $x_2-y_2$. As per the [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0094114X15000087?ref=pdf_download&fr=RR-2&rr=85347fbcaf1654b9), the relation to transfer the wrench from $r_{end}$ to $r_i$ is:

$\begin{equation}
^2\\\$_{ri} = \begin{bmatrix}(1,0,0)\times(r_i-r_{end})\\(1,0,0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\5\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}$

Now try and represent the above wrenches in $x_1,y_1$ frame, the original wrench at $r_{end }$ would be

$ ^1\\\$_{rend}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\8\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
 $
One can also obtain the same using the 'Adjoint' transformation:

$
^1\\\$_{rend} = (Adj21)^T{}^2\\\$_{rend}
$
where $Adj21$ = $\begin{bmatrix} R_{21} & 0\\ [T]R_{21} & R_{21} \end{bmatrix}$

Now, again using the relation from the paper, shifting $^1\\\$_{rend}$ to an equivalent wrench at $r_{i}$ would be:

$ ^1\\\$_{ri}=\begin{bmatrix}
(-5,0,0)\times(0,1,0)\\(0,1,0)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0\\-5\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

As per my understanding, $^1\\\$_{ri}$ should be equal to $(Adj21)^T{}^2\\\$_{ri}$, but it is not. I cannot figure out why. I would deeply appreciate any insights on this.